# Opengl version problem on MESA

Tags: vmware, opengl, versions, mesa, vmware-fusion

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Vmware Fusion 6 on my Macbook Pro Retina (which supports OpenGL upto version 4.1)

I have installed MESA by using following command

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

but now when I run the following command for checking version

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

It shows me

```
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.0
```

MESA 10.1 support OpenGL 3.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but why I'm getting still 2.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

VMware Fusion 6 supports OpenGL version upto 2.1. So if even GPU (Graphics Card) support the version 3.x or may be 4.x but VMware Fusion 6 can only provide support upto version 2.1

Update: The latest version 8 of VMware fusion supports OpenGL upto version 3.3